# ServiceStack validation not displaying messages

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack (with the new API) and trying to validate a DTO. Just created some simple code to simulate a validation but it's apparently not firing or at least it's not showing the errors on the response as expected. My code is as follows:

DTO:

```
[Route("/users/login")]
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The validator itself:

```
public class UserLoginValidator : AbstractValidator<UserLogin>
{
    public UserLoginValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Get, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter your e-mail.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid e-mail.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter your password.");
        });
    }
}
```

Configuring the validation in the host:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(UserLoginValidator).Assembly);
```

And the service:

```
public class LoginService : Service
{   
    public object Get(UserLogin request)
    {
        var response = new { SessionId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        return response;
    }
}
```

Is there any other config or adjustment that needs to be made to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the correct service stack version? I just pasted your code into a new ServiceStack project and it works. I got the correct validation error messages.

Comment: The version I'm using is 3.9.28.

Comment: So what is the response when you make a call to "/users/login" without parameters?

Comment: @rocco the current version is v3.9.32 - always update to latest to make sure it's still an issue.

Comment: @kampsj When I make a call, it returns the guid I created. It looks like the validation is not wired to the service.

Comment: @mythz forgot to check the updates for some time. just updated to the current version. no success.

Comment: Just tried with a sample project using just the validation and it works. Guess it's something related to the other project that i'm developing, haven't figured it out where is the problem tho.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation)

> Note: The response DTO must follow the {Request DTO}Response naming
>   convention and has to be in the same namespace as the request DTO!

Try creating a class for the response

```
public class UserLoginResponse
{
    public UserLogin Result { get; set; }
}
```

And return it

```
public class LoginService : Service
{   
    public object Get(UserLogin request)
    {
        var response = new UserLoginResponse { Result = request };
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that this applies to the old version of the API. The new API does not enforce the need to have a response DTO to work. I tried to create the response DTO to see if it works, but no success.